# Responsive/adaptive photo thumbnails on a page

Tags: html, css

Scenario: I want to make a html page that has many image thumbnails (about 20). 
I want to make it adaptive/responsive. It should have 4 thumbnails in a row (see Picture1)  when it's on wider browser (such as PC browser - mozilla etc) (see Picture2)
Then, when the browser reduces it's size, it should decrease it's size.

And if the browser is too small, 1 thumbnail per row should appear (such as mobile browsers etc). (see Picture3)

It should have space in between photos (padding?)

I think this should be done using CSS?

I only have following code, which reduces thumbnail's size when browser's size is reducing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<img src="img_chania.jpg" width="460" height="345">
<p>Resize the browser window to see how the image will scale.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

P.S: EDIT, SEE THIS PHOTO FOR FURTHER CLARIFICATIONS.Thanks

[image: NEW IMAGE FOR CLARIFICATIONS]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using `media queries`

take a look at this snippet:

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 980px;  /* updated - choose whatever width you prefer */
  margin: auto  /* updated */
}
#container > div {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}
#container img {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5%
}
/*whatever width query you like for phones*/

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #container > div {
    width: 100%;
    float: none
  }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
    <img src="//lorempixel.com/1600/900" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this works to a certain extent. But the photos (the columns) doesn't stay close to each other. I want the photos to be in the center of the page and columns to be close together. Let me know if you don't understand what I say, I'll attach another picture describing what I meant. :) . will adding a table or something solve the issue?

Comment: If I understand what you mean, you don't want this to get more than X `width` because you want white margins on the sides? Because at the moment it is doing the 3 pictures above on your question

Comment: all the images stack to one column when the browser width is small that's good. but, the pictures are not close to each other and not centered on page. to clarify, another picture attached, please go through it. thanks

Comment: still don't understand what you want. You need to say what you want, and not the problems you are having if you do X or Y. Otherwise it is hard to help you.

Comment: I want the images look like image 5, I have stated what I need in the picture :), please be kind enough to go through it, then it would be clear to you.

Comment: I want the pictures to have padding, but the same time, the pictures should attract each other like magnets, and stay in the middle of the page (just like image 5 in the attached image)

Comment: I think, setting the padding to fixed amount would solve the issue. Say, every time, the images will maintain 5px padding etc, no more than that, so they don't go far away from each other when the browser increase it's page width.

Comment: So exactly what I said in my first comment :) I'm gonna update my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105274/discussion-between-dippas-and-pretty-girl).